# hawkular-metrics installation failed

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Unable to proceed with hawkular-metrics installation as hawkular_metrics_schema_job.yaml failed to find schema image.

Failed to pull image "docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-schema-installer:v3.11.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-schema-installer not found: does not exist or no pull access

cat /tmp/openshift-metrics-ansible-ABoWRf/templates/hawkular_metrics_schema_job.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hawkular-metrics-schema
  labels:
    metrics-infra: hawkular-metrics
    name: hawkular-metrics-schema
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      version: v1
      metadata:
        labels:
          metrics-infra: hawkular-metrics
          #name: hawkular-metrics
      containers:
      - name: hawkular-metrics-schema
        image: docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-schema-installer:v3.11.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: TRUSTSTORE_AUTHORITIES
            value: "/hawkular-metrics-certs/tls.truststore.crt"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /hawkular-metrics-certs
          name: hawkular-metrics-certs
        - mountPath: /hawkular-account
          name: hawkular-metrics-account
      volumes:
      - name: hawkular-metrics-certs
        secret:
          secretName: hawkular-metrics-certs
      - name: hawkular-metrics-account
        secret:
          secretName: hawkular-metrics-account
      restartPolicy: OnFailure

docker pull origin-metrics-schema-installer                                                                                                                                                  Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/origin-metrics-schema-installer ...
repository docker.io/origin-metrics-schema-installer not found: does not exist or no pull access

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, if you are using **OKD v3.10**, official docker metrics images for 3.10 are tagged as "v3.10.0-rc.0" (not "v3.10").

If you are using **3.11** they are well tagged: https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-metrics-hawkular-metrics/tags/

On the other hand 
`openshift/origin-metrics-schema-installer` doesn't exist, and someone built the image to:
https://hub.docker.com/r/alv91/origin-metrics-schema-installer/ (and he/she tagged the image as "v3.10").

So in your inventory file you should have for **OKD v3.10**:

```
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=True
openshift_metrics_cassandra_image=docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-cassandra:v3.10.0-rc.0
openshift_metrics_hawkular_metrics_image=docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-hawkular-metrics:v3.10.0-rc.0
openshift_metrics_heapster_image=docker.io/openshift/origin-metrics-heapster:v3.10.0-rc.0
openshift_metrics_schema_installer_image=docker.io/alv91/origin-metrics-schema-installer:v3.10
```

And for **OKD 3.11**:

```
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=True
openshift_metrics_schema_installer_image:docker.io/alv91/origin-metrics-schema-installer:v3.10
```

- https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/9948
- https://github.com/openshift/origin-metrics/issues/429